# How do I make this personal best highscore MySQL query more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have a database for game leaderboard highscores holding currently about 30.000 entries, and the below query looks for the personal best highscore for a certain game and player, but it takes about **60 seconds** to execute. I'm thinking there should be a much more efficient way to do this, maybe using a composite index, but which one would that be?

```
SELECT name, score, date, version, mode, attempts, time, id
FROM highscore h1
WHERE score = (
  SELECT MAX( score ) 
  FROM highscore h2
  WHERE name = h1.name && gamename = "asteroids" && name = "bob"
)
```

I currently have indexes for:

```
id
score
name
name-gamename (composite)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the query using standard SQL syntax:

```
SELECT name, score, date, version, mode, attempts, time, id
FROM highscore h1
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX( score ) 
               FROM highscore h2
               WHERE h2.name = h1.name AND h2.gamename = 'asteroids' AND h2.name = 'bob'
              );
```

For this purpose, you want a *composite* index:  `highscore(name, gamename, score)`.

If you are only looking for *one* row (even when there are ties), then this might be a wee bit faster:

```
SELECT name, score, date, version, mode, attempts, time, id
FROM highscore h 
WHERE h.gamename = 'asteroids' AND h.name = 'bob'
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The appropriate index is `highscore(name, gamename, score)`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! For reference, in my specific example, your suggestions with the new composite index took: 0.0290 sec and 0.0172 sec. Making the second one perfect for me as I only need one row in this case. Thanks!

Comment: From 60 seconds down to 0.0172 seconds . . . That's a 99.97% improvement.  Pretty good ;)